# Handling looping actions in STRIPS planning

Tags: search, planning

How can I modify STRIPS such that it avoids going in loops or repeating actions? Let's say we have A - B - C - D - E as the areas (traversing problem), they are all bidirectional. Initial state is we are At(A) and the goal is we need to be At(E). The result could be

```
`Travel(A, B) - Travel(B, C) - Travel(C, D) - Travel(D, C) -
```

`Travel(C, B) - Travel(B, C) -     Travel(C, D) - Travel(D, E)`.

In short, it went A - B - C - D - C - B - C - D - E. In the middle, it went back and forth. I need an idea on how I could solve this and if you can provide a pseudocode that would be better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're facing is that your algorithm is returning "an answer" instead of the best answer. You should take a look at search algorithms and how they guarantee finding the shortest path, as the problems are isomorphic.

There are many reasons of why you're getting those results, but in general it should be related to the search method you're using. Your algorithm tries 'going back to C' before 'advancing to E' directly because there is some kind of implicit ordering preference between nodes.

Notice that from A you can only go to B; from B you could go to C or to A - and you're going to C. Why not A again? If your algorithm doesn't get into an infinite loop going from A to B to A (...), then you're most likely not applying a simple depth-first search. The key here is to understand why the algorithm decides to go back to C upon reaching D.

---

Apart from understanding you algorithm and the input in depth, here are some ideas:

If you had a list of already-visited nodes and gave preference to non-visited nodes, perhaps you'd find a better/optimal answer. Is it at all necessary to visit a node twice if the connections between them don't change?

Alternatively, are you constraining the number of steps to reach an answer? If you know beforehand the maximum number of steps that it'd take to get to the goal, constraining your answer to that number of steps should yield the optimal answer.

Simply continuing to search - instead of halting upon reaching the first result - and then comparing alternative solutions is also a possibility. This could be terribly under-performing, but also inevitably depending on the context.